# Use Bitcoin RPC to send from many addresses to single address

Tags: json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I am looking into being able to send coins from specific addresses to a single output address using bitcoin-cli

Is this possible? What RPC command would I use? Any chance of an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that possible:

you need to know the txid and Vout index for those particular addresses when they were funded

for example here i have used 3 addressees to send some BTC  to single addresses `2N6V6Ko17CPWaZZf6YrGKeq8R1fzbqrTKLF` and if  know the txid and vout of those addresses when they were funded i will do:

1)create raw tranaction

```
syntax: createrawtransaction   [{"txid":txid,"vout":n},...] {address:amount,...} 

 bitcoin-cli -regtest createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"582283c5f2293a2cdb27173c3118ff59863d9ff2be5c3b48fa8e66509e9a7d0d","vout":1},{"txid":"3126fc2864fbf780460734dd1512b98e86f72f8e5b8b59047beae9dd859ac33a","vout":0},{"txid":"94a6701b68e38b3f980c9bf2b0e905dd7e479c7ed01590eeee20b1753c29d6af","vout":1}]' '{"2N6V6Ko17CPWaZZf6YrGKeq8R1fzbqrTKLF":"2"}'
```

2) Sign raw transaction:

```
syntax: signrawtransaction  <hexstring> [] [<privatekey1>,...] 

bitcoin-cli -regtest  Signrawtransaction hexstring_from_createRawtransaction '[]'["pvtkey_add1","pvtkey_add2","pvtkey_add3"]
```

3) send raw transaction

```
syntax: sendrawtransaction hexString

bitcoin-cli -regtest hexString_from_signrawTransction
```

Comment: Very cool stuff, Thank you... I have a couple of questions, 1) How do I find the vout number, is there a command to get that information? 2) The private keys used in the sign transaction command, those would be the private keys of the addresses associated with those transactions?

Comment: @cryptoKTM `signrawtransaction` was deprecated in v0.17 and was removed from v0.18. The alternatives are `signrawtransactionwithkey` and `signrawtransactionwithwallet`. In the above example, since you are explicitly mentioning the keys you would use the former one.

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts you should know the txid when the address was funded, by simple rpc i.e getrawtransaction on particular txid you can find the vout index
, yes they are pvt key associated with addresses

also please refer to letest  comment for upgraded versions